# sending additional client info to server in C#

Tags: c#

I have written a client program using c# socket programming which will send a file to the server. Is there any way I can send a client ID (say: 1234) to the server so that the server can recognize different clients? What modification will I have to make in the following code?

```
// Client  

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace FileTransferClient
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {             
            string fileName = @"D:\demo.txt";
            string p = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
            long s1 = f.Length;

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 1234);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected. Sending file.");

            StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream());

            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

            sWriter.WriteLine(bytes.Length.ToString());
            sWriter.Flush();

            sWriter.WriteLine(fileName);
            sWriter.Flush();

            Console.WriteLine("Sending file");
            tcpClient.Client.SendFile(fileName);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well you need to build that into your protocol somehow. At the moment your protocol appears to be file length, filename, file - you could add the ID before that, for example. Personally I'd avoid mixing text and binary data like this, but that's a slightly different matter.

Comment: You could just use the client's IP address as an ID...? This is pretty unique if you're in a LAN.